# Simulating from the Gaussian Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation, random-generation, randomness

I attempted to sample random variables from the Gaussian distribution in C using the following simulation method:

$$X_n = \sqrt{(-2\log(U_1)}\cos{(2\pi U_2)}$$

Where $U_1, U_2  \sim \mathcal{U}(0,\,1)$

I then plotted the results for 100,000 iterations:

[image: Histogram]

This didn't seem very smooth to me especially for the number of iterations.

I was wondering if there any methods which are more accurate.

Comment: This is perfectly fine method of drawing samples from normal distribution.  You are drawing *random* samples, so don't expect the output to be perfect. Moreover, how does the output look like depends also on the bins you used in your histogram, change the size of the bins and it will look more "normal" -- your methodology you used for judging normality is flawed. For more methods of sampling see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "more accurate" since you're drawing samples from a fixed distribution, but if you were using these samples for Monte Carlo you can used variance reduction techniques: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction#Underlying_principle_of_the_CRN_technique

Comment: There are no methods that are more accurate, because this one is mathematically *perfect*. (If there are any inaccuracies, they derive either from the pseudorandom number generator or from propagation of floating point roundoff error--but those problems, if present, will afflict any alternative implementation, too.) The question you ought to ask is: how can one evaluate whether data are consistent with a distribution you assume they are coming from? The answer is to apply a [goodness of fit test.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=goodness%20of%20fit%20test%20distribution)